# Insert value to a worksheet cell but keep reference path in the formula

Tags: vb.net

if i insert a value to a cell with

```
workbook = ex.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\flo\\Desktop\\Dombo\\Excel_Test\\Basis.xlsx')
ws = workbook.Worksheets[1]

ws.Range('C2').Value2 = 10
```

the reference path in the formula get lost.
How can a value be inserted and while keeping the existing formula intact?

Comment: Which "valuation" would you like to see in the cell? the constant 10? or the result of the formula?  And how would the cell decide which one to show you?  I'm afraid that it is either one or the other, and not both.  Unless the formula could be expanded to "=IF(??, then old formula, else constant)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either a cell contains a formula **or** a value. It cannot contain both. If you want to preserve the formula, change the cells the formula is based on. E.g. if the formula in `C2` is `=A2+B2`, then either change the value in `A2` or `B2` or both and leave `C2` unchanged. It's the same if you do it manually in Excel.

Comment: "Either a cell contains a formula or a value" thats true ,shame on me .I am sorry to waste time